# Query SQL Select Column Matching From Another Table

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite, dbeaver

edit : Sorry gurus, I have to rephrase my question since I forgot there are 3 tables in one query.
I have three tables with tbl_goods ,tbl_units and tbl_sat which looks like this :

tbl_goods, consists of sold goods

```
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+  
   | goods  |code   |qty    |unit   |  
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+   
   | cigar  | G001  | 1     | pack  |
   | cigar  | G001  | 2     | pcs   |
   | bread  | G002  | 2     | pcs   |   
   | soap   | G003  | 1     | pcs   |  
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

and tbl_units as below :

```
   +--------+-------------+-------+  
   | code   |ucode        |qty    |
   +--------+-------------+-------+
   | KG001  | U001        | 10    |
   +--------+-------------+-------+
```

I add letter 'K' in front of code in tbl_units to differ and make sure not collide with code in tbl_goods.

and tbl_sat as below :

```
   +--------+-------------+ 
   | ucode  | unit        |
   +--------+-------------+
   | U001   | pack        |
   +--------+-------------+
   | U002   | box         |
   +--------+-------------+
   | U003   | crate       | etc
```

so only cigar will have conversion because table units have the code

what the result I need to show as below :

```
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+  
   | goods  |code   |qty    |unit   | total  |
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+   
   | cigar  | G001  | 1     | pack  | 10     |
   | cigar  | G001  | 2     | pcs   | 2      |
   | bread  | G002  | 2     | pcs   | 2      |
   | soap   | G003  | 1     | pcs   | 1      |
   +--------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```

so if the code in goods doesn't have match in tbl_units then it will show just as qty in tbl_goods, but if they match then it will convert multiply from tbl_units

Thank you very much..really appreciated

regards

EDIT (might worked ?) :
I try to modify from @danielpr query, and this is the result
think it worked, please help to check it out

```
SELECT j.code,j.qty ,j.unit, IIF(j.unit=t.unit,j.qty*u.qty,j.fqty)  FROM tbl_goods j
LEFT JOIN tbl_units u on u.code ='K' || j.code 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sat t ON t.ucode =u.ucode  [WHERE j.code='G001']
GROUP BY j.code,j.qty
```

[WHERE ..] optional if omitted will list all items, but if I just want to check the cigar..just put WHERE CLAUSE

Comment: How can this apply to both MySQL and SQLite?

Comment: sorry, i thought the query for mysql and sqlite almost 95% identical ?, so I thought some MySql insight might help here

Comment: @Imam My answer shows a correct query, what is now still unlcear to you? I linked a fiddle, so you can verify that. Note this answer is correct for your original question. Please undo your changes and create a new question if required. No one can replicate questions and answers when the question is edited after answers have been written. Accept a correct answer and open a new question in that case.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, yeah, you right. correct.. just notice for the link, and "play around" amazing.... thanks

Comment: @Imam I edited my answer by adding a further query for your new situation. Please understand I will not delete the previous part, so people can replicate the "history" of your question. Please check if this solves your question. Next time, I think creating a new question should be prefered.

Comment: @JonasMetzler actually, nice word won't fit here, da#n, you are good... solve my "little" headache problem. one last question, if I want just to sum up the goods grouping , i tried use SUM ..not working.. should I raise new question ?

Comment: @JonasMetzler never mind, i just add SUM before CASE WHEN, and things working. You just saved my life...LOL.. amazing. thanks anyway

Comment: @danielpr yours worked as well..kudos, for two tables yours works well, though I add third table so need revised the question and just found out that break the rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, you are looking for a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE WHEN` or `COALESCE`.

Here the `CASE WHEN` option:

```
SELECT g.goods, g.code, g.qty, g.unit, 
CASE WHEN u.conversion IS NULL 
  THEN g.qty
  ELSE g.qty * u.qty
  END AS total
FROM 
tbl_goods g
LEFT JOIN tbl_units u
ON g.code = u.code
AND g.unit = u.conversion;
```

As said, `COALESCE` could also do and is a bit shorter:

```
SELECT g.goods, g.code, g.qty, g.unit, 
g.qty * COALESCE(u.qty,1) AS total
FROM 
tbl_goods g
LEFT JOIN tbl_units u
ON g.code = u.code
AND g.unit = u.conversion;
```

But I think this option has a worse readability compared to `CASE WHEN`.

Therefore, I would prefer `CASE WHEN` here.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xA0VPZS9)

**EDIT** because the authour changed the question:

According to the new description, a further table is involved and the table structure is other than described before. So, the `COALESCE` option is not possible at all in this case.
We require the `CASE WHEN` way here:

```
SELECT g.goods, g.code, g.qty, g.unit, 
CASE WHEN u.qty IS NULL OR u.ucode IS NULL OR t.unit IS NULL
  THEN g.qty
  ELSE g.qty * u.qty
  END AS total
FROM 
tbl_goods g
LEFT JOIN tbl_units u ON u.code = CONCAT('K', g.code)
LEFT JOIN tbl_sat t ON u.ucode = t.ucode AND g.unit = t.unit;
```

New sample fiddle for this new situation: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/npcDSxs1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    tbl_goods.goods
,   tbl_goods.code
,   tbl_goods.qty
,   tbl_goods.unit
,   IF(tbl_goods.unit=tbl_units.conversion,tbl_goods.qty*tbl_units.qty,tbl_goods.qty) total 
FROM tbl_goods
LEFT JOIN tbl_units ON tbl_goods.code=tbl_units.code
```

on total column, we can match whether the unit in tbl_goods is same with tbl_units, which is pack.

If it is the same, then we multiply the pack qty in tbl_units with the pack in tbl_goods, else, just return the qty of tbl_goods.

[image: screenshot]